# Javascript - Getting formatted textContent of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

Say I have the following div:

```
<div id="some-div">
   <div id="sub-div">Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <a href="https://www.example.com/">sit</a> amet, consectetur adipisici elit</div>
</div>
```

Now, when I get the textContent of this div, I get `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit`. What I want is `Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit` (It could also be other identifiers than `<b>` indicating that the "ipsum" is bold).

I do not want things like the `<a>`-Link (since that would just be `innerHTML` of the `sub-div`).

Comment: did you try with textarea? You create a temporary textarea, you put any html with tag: it remains pure text. you get content of the textarea and you remove it

Comment: What's wrong with `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might work?

convert your desired tags into non-html markup (like bb code)

read the innerText to remove all the other html markup

convert the bb code back into html

**update**

press the "CLICK" text, and the result will be printed to console

```js
function replaceTag(node, tag) {
  let tags = node.querySelectorAll(tag)
  tags.forEach( (item) => {
    item.outerHTML = `[${tag}]${item.innerHTML}[/${tag}]`
  })
}

function ex() {
  // create a clone to mutate
  let node = document.getElementById("targetNode").cloneNode(true)
  // list of desired tags
  let tags = ["b", "i", "u", "s"]
  // replace tags with bb code style markup
  tags.forEach ( (tag) => {
    replaceTag(node,tag)
  })
  // print the innerText to console (replacing bb code with html)
  console.log(node.innerText.replace(/\[([bius])\](.+?)\[\/\1\]/g,'<$1>$2</$1>'))
}
```

```html
<div id="targetNode"><span>Span</span><b>BOLD</b><i>italic</i><s>strike</s></div>
<div onclick="ex()">CLICK</div>
```

**update**

Not thoroughly tested, given a node and a list of desired tags, it should return something like innerText with the desired tags left in place (although it will not preserve any attributes associated with them)

```
function getFilteredHTML(targetNode, tags = ["b", "i", "u", "s"]) {
    let node = targetNode.cloneNode(true)
    let expr = new RegExp("\\[("+tags.join("|")+")\\](.+?)\\[\\/\\1\\]","g")
    tags.forEach( (tag) => {
        let searchTag = node.querySelectorAll(tag)
        searchTag.forEach( (item) => { item.outerHTML = `[${tag}]${item.innerHTML}[/${tag}]` } )
    })
    return node.innerText.replace(expr,'<$1>$2</$1>')
}
```